# |Android| How do i connect httpsconnection to a php

Tags: php, android, android-studio, https

I have a doubt about Android HttpsURLConnection (I never used connections between 2 computers, just simple client). The problem is I can't connect to the urlconnection.connect, for example, i tried to find the asnwer before i made this post but i always got the same answer and never worked.

My code is simple but i can't figure out how can i fix it:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    try {
        URL url= new  URL("https://example.com/api.php?uid=test1&pwd=12345");
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection= (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect(); // Here is where the error occurs
        int i= urlConnection.getResponseCode(); // Here is where the error occurs too
        System.err.println(i);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is because of https?
By the way the result of the "api.php" file is always (i didn't make that file)

```
{"Result":1}
```

And i can't get that result from the file. Please help me, Thank you.

Comment: `By the way the result of the "api.php" file is always (i didn't make that file)

{"Result":1}` Impossible as you do not read the result. So how would you know?

Comment: `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);` Remove that as it seems you wanna do a GET request with that querystring.

Comment: You will have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Google for it!

Comment: `// Here is where the error occurs` Well what kind of error? Please post the logcat!

Comment: @greenapps Good call on the NetworkOnMainThreadException reminder. Taz, if you are still learning Android I strongly suggest doing some research on Asynchronous Tasks (AsyncTask) for Network operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not give us information about the log you got while run your code. I am trying your code on my Android Studio and no error i got.

Do you add permission for accessing internet on your AndroidManifest.xml file?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

If no, please add above code on your Manifest.

You run networking operation on Main thread. Just add below code before your code:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

I suppose that error you got is about android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. So, the whole code like this:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            URL url= new  URL("https://kamus.nusagates.com");
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection= (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect(); 
            int i= urlConnection.getResponseCode(); 
            System.err.println(i);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Besides on above code will give you response 200.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

Change the API variable to the base URL of your web-based API, make the requests like this.

String myResult = Connection.Request("SubDirectory/MyFile.php", "MyData");

Your PHP fill will get

```
$_POST["Data"];
```

to catch the data for processing. I hope this helps!

```
public class Connection {
    public static String Request(String UseURL, String data) {
        String API = "http://www.example.com/API/";
        try {
                    String data = "Data=" + URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");
                    URL postURL = new URL(API + UseURL);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) postURL.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    writer.write(data);
                    writer.flush();
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String retData = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      retData += line;
                    }
                    writer.close();
                    reader.close();
                    return retData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error Connecting to Server: " + e;
        }
    }
}
```